# Unity won't export for android

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

After upgrading unity from version 5.3.4 to 2018, can't publish.

> Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
>
> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
>
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:187
>
> at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:94
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr

Comment: Any compiler errors? It is always recommended to upgrade step by step and not make huge jumps between Unity versions...

Comment: error CS1704: An assembly with the same name `unibill' has already been imported. Consider removing one of the references or sign the assembly
Assets/Plugins/unibill.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Assets/Plugins/WP8/unibill.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)

Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

Comment: there you have it .. apparently you have a PlugIn script added twice: once under `Assets/Plugins/WP8/unibill.dll` and once under `Assets/Plugins/unibill.dll`. They probably do the same so you have to find out which one you can/have to remove